# Image draw speed

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, system.drawing

i am working on a game, but currently I am running benchmarks.

If anyone can help me on this matter, I would greatly appreciate it.

What I am doing, is I fire the paint event on a panel when I click the start button, with this code:

```
    private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            pnlArea.Invalidate();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I then do this in my paint event:

```
    private void pnlArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            // Begin timing
            stopwatch.Start();

            if (gameStatus == GameStatus.PlaceHead)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(dictHead["HeadRight"], 100, 100, 15, 15);
            }

            //e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

            if (gameStatus == GameStatus.GameTest)
            {
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
                {
                    x += 15;
                    if (x > 1000)
                    {
                        x = 0;
                        y += 15;
                    }

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(body.Value, x, y, 15, 15);

                }
            }

            toolTimer.Text = Math.Round((stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000), 2).ToString() + "s";

            // Stop timing
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

This is the body part I am drawing in the code above:

[image]

This is the exact size --> 15px x 15px

but this takes up to 1.2 seconds sometimes!!!
is there a way I can improve this?

this is a sample of the end result screen:
[image]

Comment: `DoubleBuffered = true;` in  Form constructor (just below  `InitializeComponent()`). Does that help?

Comment: Yeah already tried it... but i did it in the form's properties... set Double Buffer to true.

Comment: WinForms is not a great environment for gaming.  That being said, drawing every 15 x 15 pixel image is pretty costly.  Try just drawing your squares with a drawing routine instead.  If the board doesn't have too many fireworks going on all the time, try just drawing into a bitmap and just draw the bitmap to the screen.  The PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb format is the fastest.  If a tile isn't changing, don't bother updating it either.

Comment: `pnlArea.Invalidate();` should never throw an exception.  Setting DoubleBuffer on the form won't work on your panel.  You have to inherit your own panel to turn that on at the control level.

Comment: Yep, you can throw away that try/catch and also use two nested for loops: `for (int x = 0; x < width; x+= 15) { for (int y = 0; y < height; y +=15) { ... } }` but I don't think that will help much. The problem is that you're using wrong tool.

Comment: When I draw on the form directly I am down to 0.03s

Comment: Ok wait, I created this new class: class DoubleBufferedPanel : Panel { public DoubleBufferedPanel() : base() { DoubleBuffered = true; } } and used that panel instead with buffering set to true. Solved my problem and now can continue the game, thanx everyone for all the help!!!

Comment: Take a look at Win2D http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm

Comment: Don't edit your question to post the solution, post it as an answer to the question and mark it accepted when you can. If you don't it will keep getting promoted every few months to the front page as a question with no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the information everyone gave me, I came to the conclution to double buffer the panel. This fixed my problem -->

```
class DoubleBufferedPanel : Panel { public DoubleBufferedPanel() : base() { DoubleBuffered = true; } }
```

And I just used this double buffered panel instead.

New benchmark with no flickering at all! :
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You need to think about how to minimise the number of drawing calls you make. Currently you draw 5000 small boxes in order to produce a grid. Every time you draw a box you execute several instructions and then call a graphics method to render a scaled image. This is a lot of overhead for each grid square.

So the first thing you could look at would be finding more efficient ways to draw the image - for example, `DrawImageUnscaled` might work faster than `DrawImage` and achieve the result you want. But this is *optimisation* of an inefficient algorithm - what you need to do to get a real performance benefit is see if you can adopt a new, more efficient, algorithm.

If you must render using bitmaps, then look at how the pattern repeats - could you make a bigger bitmap that provides a 4x4 or 16x16 group of cells, and render that? Or a bitmap that represents a whole column or row? Then you might render with 50 calls instead of 5000.

But if you don't need to use bitmap rendering, you may be able to do much better. For example, if you `gfx.Clear(backgroundColor)` and then draw about 140 black lines down and across, you can create the same display with only 141 calls. Or if you draw about 70 rectangles you can effectively do 2 lines per call This massively reduces the number of method calls you have to make, and allows the graphics system to draw more pixels in a burst, using highly optimised line rendering and rectangle rendering routines (in fact, the rectangle may work out significantly faster than a generalised line due to the system knowing that the lines are always vertical and horizontal).

(If there are bits that do not follow this pattern, then can you still render the background grid and then draw the changes on top?)

Next, if only small areas of the image change from one frame to the next, then your algorithm will draw 5,000 boxes even though 4999 of them are not changing (or 70 rectangles when 1 would suffice). So you can improve matters greatly if you (a) only invalidate the part of the view that needs to change, and (b) write your rendering routine to work out which grid squares are outside the clip bounds and therefore are pointless to draw. This could reduce your updates to drawing 1 rectangle instead of 5000 every frame. (Another way to achieve the same thing would be to keep the image in an offscreen bitmap, and just draw changes onto it. When you render this to the main screen display, the graphics card will clip it for you and achieve the same result - a much faster redraw speed)

It's all about achieving the same display by being "lazy" and thinking laterally to do as little work as possible. (Getting a computer to go faster always boils down to asking it to do less)